# How to group N items?

Tags: perl, set

I am working on a set partitioning problem and need a way to define all combinations of unordered bucket sizes. Given N elements and exactly M groups, find every combination of group sizes such that the sum of the group sizes is N.  Note:  The size of the bucket cannot be 0.

For example, assume 6 items need to be placed in 3 buckets.   The solution I'm looking for is:

```
([1,2,3],[1,1,4],[2,2,2])
```

To map these equally, I use a map function as follows:

```
@grouping = map { int( ($items + $_) / $groups ) } 0 .. $groups-1;
```

To get all combinations I'm thinking some kind of recursive function where each level of recursion N finds the possible values for element N in the array.   The eligible values each level can insert is >= previousLevel.  This is sort of what I'm thinking but there has got to be a better way to do this....

```
sub getList($$@){
    my $itemCount = shift;
    my $groupCount = shift;
    my @currentArray = @_;
    my $positionToFill= @currentArray;
    if($positionToFill == 0){
        my $minValue = 1;
    }
    else{
        my $minValue = currentArray[$positionToFill-1];
    }
    my $currentSum = sum(@currentArray);
    return undef if $currentSum + $minValue >= $items;

    my @possibleCombinations = ();
    for(my $i = $minValue; $i < $items - $currentSum; $i++){
        $currentArray[$positionToFill] = $i;
        if($positionToFill == $groupCount-1){
            push(@possibleCombinations, \@currentArray)
        }
        else{
            push(@possibleCombinations, getList($itemCount, $groupCount, @currentArray);
        }                        
    }
    return @currentArray;
}
```

Comment: you need to tell us what you have so far, and what your specific problem(s) is/are.

Comment: Create all combinations, and then filter out that don't meet the sum criteria.

Comment: @Ether: that works for 6 but doesn't scale so well

Comment: @ysth: sure, but the OP didn't say that performance was a priority, or mention how big the buckets might get. It's not at all clear that the homework assignment requires a more optimized solution. Also, an unefficient solution is usually better than none, and writing it can cause the insight into how to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group N items into M groups, ultimately you need a recursive function that groups N-1 (or fewer) items into M-1 groups.

```
sub partition {
    # @results is a list of array references, the part of the partitions
    # created in previous iterations
    my ($N, $M, @results) = @_;

    if ($M == 1) {
        # only one group. All elements must go in this group.
        return map [ sort {$a <=> $b} @$_, $N ], @results;
    }

    # otherwise, put from 1 to $N/$M items in the next group,
    # and invoke this function recursively
    my @new_results = ();
    for (my $n = 1; $n <= $N/$M; $n++) {
        push @new_results, partition($N-$n, $M-1,
                                map [ @$_, $n ] @results);
    }
    return @new_results;
}
```

and start the process with a call like

```
@all_partitions = partition(6, 3, []);    #  [] = list with one ref to an empty array
```

This method will produce a few duplicates that you'll have to filter out, but overall it will be pretty efficient.

Comment: No duplicates if you also pass a maximum value.